# numpy how to replace a single element in array1 with whole array2

Tags: python, numpy

say I have array1 and it equals

```
array1=np.zeros((3,3))
that means [[0 0 0]
            [0 0 0]
            [0 0 0]]
```

but if I try the following it outputs an error:

```
array2=np.array[[111,222,333],[444,555,666],[77
array1[1,1]=array2
```

so how can I **replace** every single array1 element for a different new array ?
for example

```
for i in range(3):
   for j in range (3):
       if i-j==0:
         array1[i,j]=array2
```

so it will become 3*9 instead of 3*3 ?

**edit1** :expected output for the example above

```
  [[[251, 123, 584],
    [251, 123, 584],
    [251, 123, 584]],

   [[251, 123, 584],
    [251, 123, 584],
    [251, 123, 584]],

   [[251, 123, 584],
    [251, 123, 584],
    [251, 123, 584]]]
```

Comment: Please post the expected outcome...

Comment: my bad, I'll try to include the output in a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the size (number of elements) of a numpy array. But you could use lists as intermediate step to create that final array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> array1 = np.zeros((3,3))
>>> array2 = [251,123,584]
>>> np.array([[array2 for _ in row] for row in array1.tolist()])
array([[[251, 123, 584],
        [251, 123, 584],
        [251, 123, 584]],

       [[251, 123, 584],
        [251, 123, 584],
        [251, 123, 584]],

       [[251, 123, 584],
        [251, 123, 584],
        [251, 123, 584]]])
```

With some intermediate steps:

```
# Convert the original array to a list
>>> array1.tolist()
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]]

# Iterate over all elements and replace the element by array2:
>>> [[array2 for _ in row] for row in array1.tolist()]
[[[251, 123, 584], [251, 123, 584], [251, 123, 584]],
 [[251, 123, 584], [251, 123, 584], [251, 123, 584]],
 [[251, 123, 584], [251, 123, 584], [251, 123, 584]]]

# Convert the list to a numpy array again
>>> np.array([[array2 for _ in row] for row in array1.tolist()])
...
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use lists instead of numpy arrays, you could do this:

```
array1 = [[0,0],[0,0]]
array2 = [[1,2],[3,4]]

for i in range(len(array1)):
    for j in range(len(array1[0])):
        array1[i][j] = array2

print array1
```

[**Try it online**](https://repl.it/CKxd)

If you must use numpy arrays, you could convert them to lists, then convert them back into numpy arrays after doing the above.

Comment: great I already have it in the form of a list, how can I turn it into a numpy array ? for further manupilation ?

Comment: [Try looking here.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.creation.html) I would use `numpy.array(array1)`.

Comment: You may need to [flatten the list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/2415524) first.

Answer (score 1):

If you start with an array that is large enough, you can insert a smaller array.  Broadcasting will take of replicating to match the target array.

Your expected result was 3d, not (9,9):

```
In [118]: a=np.zeros((3,3,3),int)

In [119]: a2=np.array([251,123,584])

In [120]: a[...]=a2    # short hand for a[:,:,:]

In [121]: a
Out[121]: 
array([[[251, 123, 584],
        [251, 123, 584],
        [251, 123, 584]],

       [[251, 123, 584],
        [251, 123, 584],
        [251, 123, 584]],

       [[251, 123, 584],
        [251, 123, 584],
        [251, 123, 584]]])
```

Here `a[...]=a2` is shorthand for `a[:,:,:]=a2[None,None,:]`

Using `a2[None,:,None]` or `a2[:,None,None]` will replicate the `a2` values in different dimensions.

`np.tile(a2,[3,3,1])` also works.  So does `np.resize(a2,(3,3,3))`.  It may be trickier to generalize these.

---

Testing can be clearer if you make  the dimensions different:

```
In [139]: a2=np.array([1,2,3,4])

In [140]: a[...]=a2

In [141]: a
Out[141]: 
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.]],

       [[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
        [ 1.,  2.,  3.,  4.]]])
```

Here only a 4 element `a2` will fit along the last dimension.